# Spring Boot program structure for access to data objects

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I have an spring boot app that has a mongo repository and is using spring data to connect to it. This means there's an "entity" class and then a "repository" class.

However, to actually use the repository I need spring to @Autowire my repo to a variable inside another class (we'll call it X) that might want to use it. But if the X class is itself not a spring bean, it's just a regular pojo created by "new X" somewhere then it can't make use of Autowiring and therefore cant use the repo.

This seems like a show stopper... No one could ever make use of a repo outside of some very specific situations like calling the repo directly from your RestController or whatever without any intervening logic. Yet I am sure people are using this.

So my question is how to structure code so that it can be used? Do I need to do a bunch of processing and then return back up to the controller to interact with the databases? Is there a way to create some kind of other "intermediate helper bean" to mediate the connection? What should that look like?

disclaimer: I am fairly new to spring

Comment: Can you consider instantiating `X` with a `Provider` instead of a `new`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I can post some excerpts that can clarify your situation.

```
//nothing spring specific
public class MyPojo {
  //properties
}
```

in a different package:

```
@Repository
public class MyRepositoryImpl implements MyRepository {
    //CRUD implementation or whatever
}
```

in a different package:

```
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

    @Autowired //constructor-injection
    public MyService(MyRepository myRepository) {
        this.myRepository = myRepository;
    }

    private final MyRepository myRepository;

    public void myBusinessLogic() {
        MyPojo pojo = new MyPojo(); //not dependent on Spring
        myRepository.doSomething();
        //place calls to X here as needed
    }
}
```

And finally:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    public MyController(MyService myService) {
        this.myService = myService;
    }

    private final MyService myService;

    @GetMapping("/myPage")
    public String doIt() {
       myService.myBusinessLogic();
       return "myPage";
    }  
}
```

Where `MyRepository` and `MyService` are interfaces that would contain the contract for their respective implementations.

**Single Responsibility Principle**

A major point to note is that your POJO isn't going to "use the repo" as you mention in your question.  It represents an entity and shouldn't care about any specific repository.  And this seems related to your issue - a POJO shouldn't be making calls to a repository (your "X" class in this case).  Seems like the design should be revisited if that is the case.

Comment: I think I understand and I think this makes sense. thanks

Comment: Sure, let me know whether you'd like me to clarify anything.  Stick with it - it gets easier!

Answer (score 1):

As you say, you can only autowire fields in objects that themselves are autowired. This is inherent to bean injection. You should annotate X with for instance @Component and inject it where you need it.

Comment: But X has other fields that are dependent on other things that are captured by the class calling the "new" (the request, other service calls, etc...) how can I create a @Component when the constructor needs to know those things as well?